# Using Tailwind/Flowbite: How to close a dorpdown when clicking outside?

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm trying to figure out how to close Tailwind/Flowbite dropdown when clicking outside! although its working on [here](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/dropdowns/) and clicking outside seems to be ok but not in the Test Sample code below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Sample</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

<button id="dropdownDefaultButton" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdown" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button">Dropdown button <svg class="w-2.5 h-2.5 ms-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
<path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 4 4 4-4"/>
</svg>
</button>

<!-- Dropdown menu -->
<div id="dropdown" class="z-10 hidden bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700">
    <ul class="py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="dropdownDefaultButton">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Earnings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Sign out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

I'm new to Tailwind so my tries were vary by JS only but couldn't find a proper solution. I'm trying to find a solution within the scope of Tailwind/Flowbite if it is possible. if not then JS might do. (No JQ)

any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the `<body>` element covers the entire snippet preview area. In your snippet, the dropdown will close if you click anywhere inside the `<body>`:

[image]

So we can ensure this `<body>` extends to fill the viewport by applying `min-height: 100vh` via the `min-h-screen` Tailwind class:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Sample</title>

  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="min-h-screen">

<button id="dropdownDefaultButton" data-dropdown-toggle="dropdown" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center inline-flex items-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button">Dropdown button <svg class="w-2.5 h-2.5 ms-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 10 6">
<path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 4 4 4-4"/>
</svg>
</button>

<!-- Dropdown menu -->
<div id="dropdown" class="z-10 hidden bg-white divide-y divide-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow w-44 dark:bg-gray-700">
    <ul class="py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="dropdownDefaultButton">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Earnings</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white">Sign out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
```